# Error: imagecopymerge() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: php, gd

Getting an error trying to set an image as a variable in PHP:

```
$barcode= 'barcode_test.png';
$image = ImageCreate($width, $height);
ImageCopyMerge($image,$barcode,0,0,0,0,400,100,0);
```

> PHP Warning: imagecopymerge() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given

How do I make `$barcode` a resource, not a string?

Comment: I think you use `imagecreatefrompng($barcode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have to use [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) to get a resource of the file. Try the following:

```
$barcode = imagecreatefrompng('barcode_test.png');
$image = ImageCreate($width, $height);
ImageCopyMerge($image,$barcode,0,0,0,0,400,100,0);
```

If you are using another file type you have to choose one of the following function depending on the extension: `imagecreatefromgd2`, `imagecreatefromgd2part`, `imagecreatefromgd`, `imagecreatefromgif`, `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `imagecreatefrompng`, `imagecreatefromstring`, `imagecreatefromwbmp`, `imagecreatefromwebp`, `imagecreatefromxbm`, `imagecreatefromxpm`